# Understanding associated domain services and creating custom associated domain services

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-universal-links, handoff, ios8-handoff

I've been doing a fair amount of research on universal links, handoff and associated domains on iOS. However, a lot of the documentation does go in depth of what is really happening under the hood with regards to associated domains (Well I couldn't find the documentation).

Here is what I understand so far:

Based the [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), [Hand off](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10) and [Sharing web credentials documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials/preparing_your_app_and_website_to_share) we have the following format when it comes to an associated domain:

```
<service>:<fully qualified domain>[:port number]
```

So when using universal links, the service is`applinks`. When using hand off the service is `activitycontinuation`. When sharing of web credentials the service is `webcredentials`.

Whenever an app is downloaded the`apple-app-site-association` file is downloaded and stored on the phone and a registry is kept. For example lets work now with Universal Links.

Lets say my app in its associated domains section registers: `applinks:com.example`. Now lets say that when I get a link in an email that is `www.example.com` and I press this, I assume that the OS on the phone first checks the registry of all the `applinks` saved on the device and because a given app registers to `com.example` it then simply routes the URL to the given app that registered the `com.example` associated domain.

**Question 1:Is this intuition correct?**

If this is the case, I can't see any issue as a developer by creating my own web service i.e. `mySpecialService:<Some-Domain>` and in my `apple-app-site-association` file have something like:

```
{
   "mySpecialService": {
       "apps": [    "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.DemoApp",
                    "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.DemoAdminApp" ]
    }
}
```

**Question 2: Can developers create their own associated domain services? Or are associated domain services reserved by Apple?**

Comment: I've never heard of someone doing this, so I presume it's not permitted. You may want to test for yourself. However, worth pointing out that the `applinks:` notation uses _standard_ URL formatting, _not reverse_. In other words, `applinks:example.com`, NOT `applinks:com.example`

Comment: Did you found an answer?